# Von Neumann entropy of a quantum state vs Von Neumann entropy of a system

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, information

Using the [Chuang and Nielsen Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107002176) book, for an introductory course in Quantum Information, I stumbled on an ambiguous (at least for me) use of the Von Neumann entropy, being used sometimes for quantum state (for example $S(\rho)$) and sometimes for quantum systems:

> Suppose distinct quantum systems A and B have a joint state ρAB. Then the joint
>   entropy for the two systems satisfies the inequalities
>   $$
> S(A,B) \le S(A)+SA(B)
> $$

Sometimes it is said that $S(A)$ is the entropy of a state in the system $A$, but the example cited above seems not the case.

My question is, what is the meaning of the Von Neumann entropy of a system? Does it always is related to the entropy of a state in the aforementioned system or has it a different meaning?

Comment: what do you mean by "system" as opposed to "state"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximize over all states $\rho$ on A. For the classical example, one bit can be in two states but we have not stated the probabilities. The maximum entropy is when $p=1/2$. So by an abuse of notation we can call it 1 bit of information even if it might really store less information.